# Dropzone js file removing

Tags: dropzone.js

I have implemented Dropzonejs to upload files, I have a very simple question, how can I remove a file from the box, actually, there is a 'X' when you upload a file but it's not clickable. any idea?

i'm not allowed to post a screenshot so here is an external link:

[enter link description here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=w6w7ya&s=8#.VZdgzOf9F0s)

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration add the `addRemoveLinks` options with the value of "dictRemoveFile"

```
// "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  maxFilesize: 2,
  addRemoveLinks: "dictRemoveFile", //this is what you want to add
};
```